# If $\gcd(A, B) = 1$, what sufficient condition(s) (if any) guarantee $\gcd(A, C) = \gcd(B, C) = 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

The title says it all.

> If $\gcd(A, B) = 1$, what sufficient condition(s) (if any) guarantee $\gcd(A, C) = \gcd(B, C) = 1$?

For example, $A = 3$, $B = 4$ and $C = 5$ satisfy the constraints.

Are there any other examples?

(Please feel free to remove the **pythagorean-triples** tag if it is not appropriate for this question.)

Comment: For example, $A=3,B=4$ and $C=6$ does not satisfy the constraints. Why not take the conditions that $C$ is coprime to given coprime $A,B$, so coprime to $AB$? If you only look for sufficient conditions, then take the condition $C=1$.

Comment: Sufficient condition: $\gcd(AB,C)=1$.  Also necessary.